# why did I get a decimal point by using loadstring in Lua

Tags: lua, decimal-point

I have a scenario that I need pass dynamic operators into `loadstring`. This is where I found it and I don't understand.

Please see the following output:

```
> a = '3'
> b = '7'
> operator = '+'
> loadstring("return a" .. operator .. "b")()
10.0 -- Why do I get then with a decimal point.
> loadstring("return 3" .. operator .. 7)()
10   -- But this one is not?
```

Can anyone explain what's going on inside `loadstring` since I thought I should get the same result?

Comment: You are calculating an expression on STRINGS (strings implicitly get converted to floating point numbers, that's one of strange features of Lua 5.3).  Try to convert them to numbers manually: `loadstring("return tonumber(a)"..operator.."tonumber(b)")()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.1) says this about arithmetic operators applied to strings:

> if both operands are numbers or strings that can be converted to numbers (see §3.4.3), then they are converted to floats

Perhaps you want

```
loadstring("return " .. a .. operator .. b)()
```

instead of

```
loadstring("return a" .. operator .. "b")()
```